# Programmatic equivalent for scanning by a custom annotation

Tags: spring

I have been programatically configured AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext to run a web application. But I would like to add some custom logic provided by annotation.

What is programmatic equivalent code piece for this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.aaa">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.annotation.Fooish" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my application to use annotation instead of programmatic scanning.

```
@ComponentScan(
                 basePackages = {"xxx", "yyy"},
                 useDefaultFilters = true,
                 includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value com.annotation.Fooish.class)}
)
```